# Proper use of reduce, nested loops

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Below is an implementation of Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm. It's input `graph` is represented as an association list of source nodes to assoc of target node and arc weight.

My question is about the following, am I missing a way of simplifying `min-path` function used in reduce? Maybe the great and powerful `loop` could do `reduce`'s job?

```
(defun dijkstra (source target graph)
  (labels ((min-path (&optional arc-1 arc-2)
             (let ((price-1 (cdr arc-1))
                   (price-2 (cdr arc-2)))
               (cond 
                 ((and (not (null arc-1)) (not (null arc-2))) (if (< price-1 price-2)
                                                                arc-1 arc-2) )
                 ((and (not (null arc-1)) (null (arc-2))) arc-1) 
                 ((and (not (null arc-2)) (null (arc-1))) arc-2))))
           (get-best-path (visited)
             (reduce #'min-path (loop for pick in visited 
                                      for start = (car pick) 
                                      for cost = (cdr pick) 
                                      append (loop for arc in (cdr (assoc start graph))
                                                   when (null (assoc (car arc) visited))
                                                   collect (cons (car arc) (+ cost (cdr arc))))))))
    (loop named main-loop
          with visited = (list (cons source 0))
          for best-arc = (get-best-path visited)

          when (not (null best-arc)) 
          do (push best-arc visited)  
          until (or (null best-arc)
                  (eql (car best-arc) target)) 
          finally 
          (format t "Found shortest path from ~A to ~A: ~A~%" source target best-arc)
          (return-from main-loop (cdr best-arc)))))
```

I'm new to Lisp, and I would appreciate any advice, especially on bad Lisp habits and  bad Lisp style in my code, thanks.

*UPD*: new version with review comments applied - no warnings, unlike the original version.

```
(defun dijkstra (source target graph)
  (labels ((min-path (&optional arc-1 arc-2)
             (cond ((and arc-1 arc-2) (if (< (cdr arc-1) (cdr arc-2)) arc-1 arc-2))
                   (arc-1 arc-1)
                   (arc-2 arc-2)
                   (t nil)))
           (get-best-path (visited)
             (reduce #'min-path 
                     (loop for pick in visited 
                           for start = (car pick) 
                           for cost = (cdr pick) 
                           append (loop for arc in (cdr (assoc start graph))
                                        unless (assoc (car arc) visited)
                                        collect (cons (car arc) (+ cost (cdr arc))))))))
    (loop with visited = (list (cons source 0))
          for best-arc = (get-best-path visited)
          when best-arc do
          (push best-arc visited)  
          until (or (null best-arc) (eql (car best-arc) target)) 
          finally (return (cdr best-arc)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `(not (null x))` is not very idiomatic; just use `x` instead.

Next, you are not handling *all* the cased in your `cond` (and you obviously mean `(null arc-2)` and not `(null (arc-2))`). If fact, I would drop the `let` and use nested `if`s instead.

Finally, to answer your original question: of course `loop` can do everything `reduce` can, but if your intent is clearer with the latter, use it!

EDIT: `unless` is more idiomatic than `when (null ...)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, the `(null (arc-2))` is an error that doesn't prevent the program from properly executing. Regarding *all* cases, it is "merely" a discipline matter right?

Comment: If this error does not prevent proper execution, you are not testing all cases in your inputs. Checking all cases in `cond` is needed for clarity of your intent and error checking.